# SQL DB Best Practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

when it comes to SQL DB schema, is it a better practice to add more "boolean" like fields or is it better to keep one field and have it be "mode" representing different combinations? For either case, can you elaborate why it's better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about specific values of things . . . `IsActive`, `IsBlue`, `IsEnglishSpeaking`, then have a separate flag for each one.

There are a few cases when having a combined "mode" might be beneficial.  However, in most cases, you want your columns to represent variables that you care about.  You don't want to have special logic dissecting particular values.

In MySQL, a `boolean` value actually occupies 1 bytes (8 bits).  MySQL has other data types such as enums and sets that might do what you want.  The `bit` data type, despite its name, does not seem to pack flags into a single byte (which happens on other databases).

Comment: does the bit datatype actually only use 1 bit? how does it store this internally? does it concatenate 8 of these fields into a byte and having only 1 bit field will still take up 1 byte all the way to 8 bits? Thanks

Comment: @user1181950 . . . Alas, MySQL is not SQL Server and the two handle the `bit` data type very differently.  Flags do not seem to pack in MySQL.  Here is an interesting discussion:  http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get where you're coming from... The answer is: use boolean for `has_property` scenarios, and something else for everything else.

Basically, you're talking about a "flag" versus a "variable". Flags are boolean. Everything else has some other type (integer, datetime, etc...). Databases have strict typing, so either work with a strictly typed language or make sure the data you pass to you DB is correctly typed. DBs have incredible flexibility, as well. For instance, [BLOBs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) can store arbitrary binary data (like pickled Python).